# Given a list of numbers predict the next in sequence

Tags: php, numbers

I'm using PHP, I have a list of numbers with a min of 1 and a max of 10:

1,2,4,10,4,3,1,6,9,8,2,10,5,6,7,3,1...

Is there a way to find the next logic number in the sequence (or at least the possible number/s)?

I think I can loop thru the array and find the one that came up least, but I'm not sure it will be working.

Comment: So the next number can be 1-10 but not same as last?

Comment: Exactly, actually can also be the same if is correct in the sequence

Comment: If you are looking at only integer sequences it might just be easier to just look it up here: https://oeis.org

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of functions that test that list of numbers for a specific pattern yes, however that is much different that what humans do which is to "discover" a pattern. Humans also test for previous patterns they have seen in the past, however we are capable of discovering a pattern we haven't seen before with the algorithms inside are head. If you want the code to try to discover patterns in your list of numbers, that would be Artificial Intelligence coding. It very much does exist, though it's a big topic all together.

I hope that explanation helps :)

---

Edited: 
Here's a link if you are interested in knowing more about Artificial Intelligence coding:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjZBTDzGeGg&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63gFHB6xb-kVBiQHYe_4hSi

Comment: I see. Is there a practical example for this?
Perhaps there is a math function I have to study first, but I don't know where to start from.

Comment: @Mr.Web a pratical example of which part of what I said? AI coding or pattern testing?

Comment: AI coding for the above (if not too complicated)

Comment: @Mr.Web I placed a link for you in my answer :). Oh and if my answer worked for your question, please accept it with a green check mark so that future readers know it was the one that worked